# getting “Only valid bearer authentication supported” when searching for artist info

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify

I am trying to get artist information using the Spotify API. Authorization key works with [Spotify console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-search-item/). but when I am running my python file in my machine it showing error only valid bearer authentication supported.

```
import requests

import json
import pprint

endpoint_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?"

# OUR FILTERS
query = "john"
typ = "artist"
limit = 1
offset = 1
token="BQCjNYC2q_m1e_JAQgttZ3F-1CW1mnai9E2psfLbwY15kbtd7u2sjuPiF7ld8hbUshPJGLlBK3kLDIebgtk_K3bDrggExZDJ1zEMb8WVvV1DEx2rUK2youoeqT1rmXDT99P04rs8O0ie"

query = f'{endpoint_url}q={query}&type={typ}&limit={limit}&offset={offset}'

response = requests.get(query,
                        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json",
                                 "Authorization": token})
json_response = response.json()
pprint.pprint(json_response)
```

Result:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Only valid bearer authentication supported',
           'status': 400}}
```

Comment: I think the `Authorization` must be like this: `"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token`

Comment: Yeah. Thanks it's working now.

Comment: Great. I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append 'Bearer' to the value of the Authorization header:

```
"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token
```

**edit:**

As you are using Python 3.6 or further:

```
"Authorization": f'Bearer {token}'
```

Comment: since it's python3 isn't "Authorization":f'Bearer {token}' better?